# Problem with the icon of my vscode extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I create an vscode extension.

This is my `package.json`

```json
{
  "name": "polyglot",
  "displayName": "polyglot",
  "description": "polyglot",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "publisher": "ActivityBartool",
  "engines": {
    "vscode": "^1.74.0"
  },
  "categories": [
    "Other"
  ],
  "activationEvents": [
    "onView: nodeDependencies"
  ],
  "main": "./out/extension.js",
  "contributes": {
    "views": {
      "path": [
        {
          "id": "nodeDependencies",
          "name": "",
          "contextualTitle": "Path"
        }
      ]
    },
    "viewsContainers": {
      "activitybar": [
        {
          "id": "path",
          "title": "Polyglot",
          "icon": "media/path.png"
        }
      ]
    },
    "commands": [
      {
        "command": "extension.welcome",
        "title": "Welcome",
        "category": "Polyglot"
      }
    ]
  },
  "icons": {
    "light": "media/path.png",
    "dark": "media/path.png"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "vscode:prepublish": "npm run compile",
    "compile": "tsc -p ./",
    "lint": "eslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "watch": "tsc -watch -p ./"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.25",
    "@types/node": "^16.18.34",
    "@types/vscode": "^1.73.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.7.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.7.0",
    "eslint": "^8.26.0",
    "typescript": "^5.2.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.5.1",
    "node-fetch": "^3.3.2"
  }
}
```

I upload my extension on market place but when I install it the icon of my extension doesn't appear in the activity bar under the other.
Can someone help me to solve my problem? Why my icon doesn't appear when I install my extension? For now my extension is only for vscode app and not vscode web

When i do F5 the icon appear but if I upload in the market place and i install the extension the icon doesn't appear.

Comment: Test it with something like `"icon": "$(eye)"` in your `activitybar` viewContainer just to see if that works.  Also you may need to simply use a form like: ` "icon": "./media/path.png"` so that it is relative to the location of the `package.json` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in `package.json` the property is `icon` and it does not support `light` and `dark`

```json
  "icon": {"media/path.png"},
```

Comment: If i write like this give me errors. Icons is use to put the immagine in all version of vscode both black and white. In fact, when i start my extension I see the icon. The problem start when I put in on marketplace and i install the extension. When I install it I can't see the icon in the activity bar.

Comment: @blackangel this is the form I use in all my extensions, I can't see an example of the dark/light in the doc pages for extension icons, true for UI icons